# Cancel onclick event for one column in table

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I've done some digging and been unable to find a solution to this little problem. I have a table where I've made each row clickable using:

`<tr class="clickable" onclick="window.document.location='$link';">`

I'd like to make this work for all but the last column in the table but all the solutions I've found so far involve jQuery. Is there a way of "cancelling" the row onclick event for one column?

TIA

Comment: why dont you simply remove the onclick from this tr ?

Comment: I'd hoped to make the entire row clickable except the last column and using onclick in <tr> rather than a separate one in each <td> seems a neater solution.

Comment: try using adding onclick="return false" in last td

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the code - http://jsbin.com/iLISUDu/2/

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr onclick='window.location.href="google.com";'>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>We are cells</td>
        <td onclick='event.stopPropagation();return false;'>Click Me</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Not sure I've made myself clear but I wanted to make the entire row clickable except one column, hence putting the onlick in the <tr> element rather than in each <td> element.

Comment: Many thanks Rohit, that worked perfectly. I've marked the question as answered but it won't let me up-vote it.

Comment: This has caused another slight problem. The last column (the one I don't want the rows onclick event to apply to) is a checkbox, to allow the user to select multiple rows). The stopPropagation procedure has the desired effect on the onclick event but also prevents the checkbox from working. Any ideas?

Comment: Have found solution: remove the "returan false" and it seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

try

`<td onclick="(function(e){e.preventDefault();})">A</td>`

Answer (score 0):

Click events can be cancelled by returning false from the handler event.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work if you are returning false in the <td> element of a column when you are trying the cancel the onclick of the <tr> element for just that one column.